# different performances on real devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am developing an iOS application on iPad Air (iOS 7.1) in xcode5. Everything goes well. However, when I deploy it on other devices (like iPad mini, iPad Retina, with the same iOS 7.1), the performance seems to be slower. Even, touching a button, the effect happens slower quite clearly.

Do you know why? and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Well since the devices have different CPU and performance it different. But without any code we can not tell you where the issue lies.

Comment: I know that different devices have different CPU, and performances obviously are different. However, even touching a button is also slower around 0.5 seconds. How can that be?

Comment: How can well tell unless you give a minimal example of the isseu

Comment: Yes, please be more specific, give examples, code snippets or more information, otherwise it is completely impossible to answer this question. A touch on a button shouldn't have different (notable) reaction times on different devices, so the issue must be somewhere within your app.

Comment: It happens on every buttons. So how can I show you code for that?

Comment: @chipbk10 if you create an new empty app, just one button is there a delay

Comment: @rckoenes: Good advice, perhaps it is a good start for testing. I will give it a try.

Comment: @rckoenes: No, the performance is quite good.

Comment: Then the issue lies with the code you have written, thus without posting that code we are not able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool *Instruments* to anaylze the performance of your app, check out this tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments--mobile-9403

To launch *Instruments*, **click and hold the "play"-button in Xcode and choose *Profile***.